# Function with two complex variables

Tags: complex-numbers, special-functions

I have a project in an advanced mathematical methods lecture regarding analyticity of functions with two complex variables. My question is, are there some interesting/special functions in $\mathbb C^2$ that appear in physics?

Comment: As you may already know, complex calculus is quite important in theoretical physics, and appears everywhere. However it is hard to cite a function $f(z_1,z_2)$ in particular which would be fundamental. However these function of multiple complex variables appear a lot in quantum field theory and conformal field theory. In QFT, it is interesting to analyse the complex structure of scattering amplitudes e.g. Landau equations. In CFT of 2 dimensions (e.g. string theory), we use directly complex coordinates to represent space, and correlation functions are functions of multiple complex variables

Comment: @AdrienMartina I thought that this is the case, but I couldn't find an example of a function with 2 complex variables

Comment: @Qmechanic I did also posted the question there, but thought that I should do it also here because somebody could maybe more easily know a connection to physics topics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may already know, complex calculus is quite important in theoretical physics, and appears everywhere. However it is hard to cite a particular function $f(z_1,z_2)$ which would be fundamental to physics.
Some examples of the appearance of such functions of multiple complex variables appear in quantum field theory and conformal field theory. Let me cite two examples

In quantum field theory, it is useful to analyze the complex structure of scattering amplitudes (their poles, their branch cuts, ...) to grasp some of their properties. The process of two incoming particles scattering in two outgoing particles is characterized by an amplitude depending on the external momenta. Thinking of this function of momenta as a function on the complex plane is very useful. For details on this, you can have a look at the book "The Analytic S-Matrix", in particular section 2 deals with function of multiple complex variables to derive Landau equations.

In 2 dimensional conformal field theories (e.g. string theory), we use directly complex coordinates to represent spacetime, because conformal transformations are related to holomorphic functions. Correlation functions (in particular, scattering amplitudes) are then naturally functions of multiple complex variables representing space points. For more details on this, you can have a look at the String Theory books from Polchinski, or if you're primarily interested in CFT, the Conformal Field Theory book by Di Francesco, Mathieu and Sénéchal.

Comment: Thank You very much!! I will try to get the books somehow and look at it :)